# MySQL Design for Handling Products with Custom Fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an web application where an product can be of a few different types (furniture types, actually) and depending upon those types, the product has certain fields associated with it.

**Quick Background**: I'm using MySQL and PHP with CakePHP as my framework. The answer I'm looking for doesn't necessarily need to be "CakePHP-like"; I'd prefer a general MySQL best database design answer first and formost.

So, I can think of two options:

1. **Single Table Option** – I have one table `products` with all of the possible fields and just leave the fields that aren't used for that specific product as `null`. This is I think the simplest design, but would take a bit of shoe horning in the integration (as my model would need to keep track of type and what fields are to be actually updated based on that type.)
2. **Multiple Product Table Options** – Each product gets its own table with the proper fields for that specific product type. There is a master table (`products`) that has at least three fields `id` (primary key), `productType` (to find the right table) and `productTypeId` (which joins the product table to the specific product table.

I'm leaning heavily on #1, but wanted to get some other people's thoughts.

Let me know if you need more details! **Thanks!**

**Update:** I would only be expecting a small-ish set of furniture types (<10 to start, max ever would be 20).

Comment: I think it would be really helpful to know how many rows you expect, and how often you think you would need additional columns for new furniture types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose a solution to your problem, at least id you have many different kind of attributes for your products, might be to use [Entity-attribute-value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

Basically, you could have :

- One simple `Product` table, that contains one line per product, and stores the kind of data that each product has *(examples : a name, a price, a quantity in stock)*
- And another table, that, for each product, stores the attributes that product can have -- one attribute per line, which means several lines per product.

Of course, you'll also need some kind of "reference system", that defines :

- The list of possible attributes
- For each attribute, the list of possible values
- And for each type of product, the different attributes that can be associated with it.

If you don't want to put in place that kind of system, I would go with something like your second solution :

- I don't like the idea of the first solution -- those NULL fields are not great
- With multi-table options, I would use :

  - One Product table, that contains one line for each product
  - Several ProductTYPE tables

    - and, speaking as classes/objects, those `ProductTYPE` tables would inherit from `Product`
    - Which means that, for each product, you'd have one line in `Product` and one line in the corresponding `ProductType` table.

Comment: Agree with the AEV model and otherwise option 2. You could use the single table option though, but only if there aren't that many differences between the types. But when all these product types have many different values (and thus columns) it just gets very messy very quickly, and in the long run that's probably not what you want.

Comment: This sounds like a good plan. Will implement tonight! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an object or array or even xml? 
1.Use an array or object and and then serialize it:

```
$details = serialize(array('width'=>'1meter','color'='beatiful'));
```

Or use xml and store only the path to the xml file in the database.

Comment: I think in this case, I'd prefer to have the data stored in the DB in "raw" columns as opposed to an abstract format (serialized or something else) so that I can use the speed of the DB for sorting and what not. Thanks for the idea, though.